# Can we use 2 repos in one controller? (Symfony 4.4)

Tags: symfony

I am working on a Symfony backend and Angular Front and am testing the backend before linking the 2.

I am trying to use an event to update datas on 2 tables but didn't succeed and was wondering if it is good to use 2 repos in a method (I try with the index one to start) :

```
    class ProductsInfoOrganisedController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="products_info_organised_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $productsInfoOrganiseds = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(ProductsInfoOrganised::class)
            ->findAll();

        $productsInfoOrganisationRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(ProductsInfoOrganisation::class);
        $linesCorrespondingInOrganisation = $productsInfoOrganisationRepo->find(5);

        return $this->render('products_info_organised/index.html.twig', [
            'products_info_organiseds' => $productsInfoOrganiseds,
            'products_info_organisations' => $linesCorrespondingInOrganisation 
        ]);

        dd($linesCorrespondingInOrganisation );
        
    }
}
```

As soon as I load the index page (in twig, as I am testing the backend code), I get an error message:

```
    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.shop_id AS shop_id_2, t0.pack_id AS pack_id_3, t0.adapte_gaucher AS adapte_gaucher_4, t0.crit1 AS crit1_5, t0.crit2 AS crit2_6, t0.crit3 AS crit3_7 FROM products_info_organisation t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [5]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.adapte_gaucher' inconnu dans field list
```

Can I use 2 repos in the controller?
Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried Cerad solution and when I try to update, I get the following message but no action on the database. And i tried Inmarelibero's solution to clear the cache (globally and metadata individually and still the same message).
λ php  bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

```
 The following SQL statements will be executed:

 ALTER TABLE products_info_organisation ADD adapte_gaucher INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE shop_id shop_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE pack_id pack_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit1 crit1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit2 crit2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit3 crit3 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
 ALTER TABLE products_info_organised CHANGE shop_id shop_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE pack_id pack_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE adapte_gaucher adapte_gaucher INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE triABC triABC INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE triACB triACB INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE tri_id tri_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit1 crit1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit2 crit2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE crit3 crit3 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I am not sure what went wrong.

I even tried with the method I would use to send data to my Angular Front:

```
        public function index(ProductsInfoOrganisedRepository $productsInfoOrganisedRepository, ProductsInfoOrganisationRepository $productsInfoOrganisationRepository)
    {
//        return $this->json($productsInfoOrganisedRepository->findAll(), 200, []);
        return $this->json($productsInfoOrganisationRepository->findAll(), 200, []);
//        return $this->json($productsInfoOrganisedRepository->findAll(). $productsInfoOrganisationRepository->findAll(), 200, []);
    }
```

I still get the same error message as if I was using only Symfony.

Comment: Yes you can use as many repositories as you like.  The error message implies that your Doctrine entity mappings do not match your database schema.  Try running: bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

Comment: Hello, can you show us dev.log? I want to see errors

Comment: Please share more details - why shouldn't that work? The given error message does not indicate any problem related to the question. Additionally, why not inject these repositories through DI?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I am not sure what you mean (DI) Dependency Injection? I've never use it. I'd give a look to see how that works.
I think, in my case, it didn't work as I am testing in Twig the render but in the end, I should create a json file rendered in Angular. But the SQL was what was bothering me

Comment: @AndreyMashukov, here is the dev.log https://file.io/8IZ9R7Bl1LDo . Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/ for an excellent explanation about the usage of repositories as services, also containing parts about controllers

Comment: give me few minutes, have just downloaded it

Answer (score 2):

seems that Doctrine metadata are outdated, try to clean the cache

Comment: Also it can be the reason of problem, sometimes strange errors in Symfony can be fixed be cache removing

Answer (score 1):

according your errors from log file, I think that error located in the Entity Mapping, please check that column `adapte_gaucher` in your table exists and mapping is set correctly.

```sh
cat var/log/dev.log | grep CRITICAL
```

Error:

```
[2021-01-07 15:38:06] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException: "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.shop_id AS shop_id_2, t0.pack_id AS pack_id_3, t0.adapte_gaucher AS adapte_gaucher_4, t0.crit1 AS crit1_5, t0.crit2 AS crit2_6, t0.crit3 AS crit3_7 FROM products_info_organisation t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [5]:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.adapte_gaucher' inconnu dans field list" at C:\wamp64\www\shops\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\InvalidFieldNameException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.shop_id AS shop_id_2, t0.pack_id AS pack_id_3, t0.adapte_gaucher AS adapte_gaucher_4, t0.crit1 AS crit1_5, t0.crit2 AS crit2_6, t0.crit3 AS crit3_7 FROM products_info_organisation t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [5]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.adapte_gaucher' inconnu dans field list at C:\\wamp64\\www\\shops\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:79, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.adapte_gaucher
```

Problem does not depend on amount of used repositories, You can use many repos as you need, so, please check the Mapping